# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at jdbc.DatabaseAccess.doGet(DatabaseAccess.java:25)

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

**I am trying simple login authentication using servlets and jdbc connection to MySQL database. After executing it on tomcat server I am getting following error:**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at jdbc.DatabaseAccess.doGet(DatabaseAccess.java:25)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
May 04, 2015 6:06:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/servelt] has started
May 04, 2015 6:06:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/servelt] is completed
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at jdbc.DatabaseAccess.doGet(DatabaseAccess.java:25)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am sharing the content of all files:
DatabaseAccess.java

```
package jdbc;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
@WebServlet("/DatabaseAccess") 
public class DatabaseAccess extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            String title = "Database connect";
            String docType ="<!doctype html>\n";
            out.println(docType +"<html>\n" +"<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +"<body>\n" +
                 "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n");
            try 
            {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");  
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from student");
            while(rs.next()){
                int id  = rs.getInt("id");
                int marks = rs.getInt("marks");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                out.println("ID: " + id + "<br>");
                out.println(", name: " + name + "<br>");
                out.println(", marks: " + marks + "<br>");
             }
             out.println("</body></html>");
             rs.close();
             stmt.close();
             con.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

    }

}
```

web.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>servelt</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>DatabaseAccess</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>jdbc.DatabaseAccess</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>DatabaseAccess</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/DatabaseAccess</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Please help me to get out of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add your mysql connector jar to WEB-INF\lib folder to be loaded by tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Exception is for `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` add the respective jar in your lib folder or classpath

Answer (score 0):

Your source code is correct.The exception shows that,mysql connector is not in your libraries.You must add mysql jdbc connector to your application *classpath* and *WEB-INF/lib*.If you add only *classpath* and run any method individually,exception will not occur but from servlet or jsp if you call this method you will get error.For solution you must add mysql jdbc connector jar also to *WEB-INF/lib*